# How to solve a kummer equation in term of confluent hyp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How we  find the solution of Kummer equation by using  confluent hypergeometric function?
please do help.

Comment: This is straightforward : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html